# Java priorityquues

Tags: java

Can someone help me to write a code that change the emergencyNr to a specific Patient? I want to search for a Patient in the Priorityqueue and if its in the queue i want to change the emergencyNr.

When i try to call setEmergencyNr from my other code it doesent work because of the setEmergencyNr-method not is static?

```
public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient> {
    private int id;
    private static String name;
    private int emergencyNr = 0;

    public Patient(int id, String name, int emergencyNr) { // Patient
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.emergencyNr = emergencyNr;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the emergencyCase
     */
    public int isEmergencyCase() {
        return emergencyNr;
    }

    /**
     * @param emergencyCase
     *            the emergencyCase to set
     */
    public void setEmergencyCase(int emergencyCase) {
        this.emergencyNr = emergencyNr;
    }

    // ----NYTT

    public int compareTo(Patient otherRequest) {
        return Integer.compare(otherRequest.emergencyNr, emergencyNr);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Patient [Name= " + name + ", emergencyNr=" + emergencyNr + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I am a bit curious why `name` is static. Maybe you should research a little bit what the `static` keyword exactly does.

Comment: Please, take a look at your `setEmergencyCase` method, do you really assign there a value from given parameter?
Edit: if you have any additional info to make question more solvable feel free to edit the question and input there required informations.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your method:

```
public void setEmergencyCase(int emergencyCase) {
    this.emergencyNr = emergencyNr;
}
```

You aren't setting there a new emergency number, but you assign there the same value as it was before, you need to switch assigned value to one represented by yours method parameter which is `emergencyCase` like:

```
 this.emergencyNr = emergencyCase;
```